# Enforce naming conventions on sql server

Tags: sql-server

Is there any way to enforce naming conventions on sql server 
regarding Primary Keys /Forign Keys / Default Values .. etc'
for example :

- **PrimaryKey** - PK_TableName_FieldName
- **ForignKey** - FK_TableName_FieldName
- **Default Value** - DF_TableName_FieldName ...

in addition if possible to prevent adding default value on table field without
creatring a defined constaint ( prevent auto generated constaint )
the main purpose is to prevent difference between dev and prod scripts

thanks

Comment: If you are using a script to create your objects in dev how can they not have the same name in prod? I suspect that your team is not scripting things. And no, there is no way to prevent this from happening. There are however many tools out there to help identify schema differences between databases.

Comment: Use [DDL Triggers](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175941.aspx) that fail the change/addition if the constraint names are not to your liking?

Comment: the migretion between DEV to prod is done with regdate SQL COMPARE. which helps you with schema/data compare. BUT yet we want to find a way to enfouce namaing on constraints , indexes , forign keys . to prevent system generated names.